# Cannot find namespace in project oxford name space in sample app of microsoft cognitive services

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to create a simple app that shows near real time emotions with a live web cam. I am using this guide:

https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/emotion-api/documentation/emotion-api-how-to-topics/HowtoAnazlyzeVideo_Emotion

I've Downloaded the sample app:
https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Samples-VideoFrameAnalysis/

but I am unsure how I could make it run. the README says:
. Get API keys for the Vision APIs. 
2. Open the sample in Visual Studio 2015, build and run the sample applications:
    - For BasicConsoleSample, the Face API key is hard-coded directly in BasicConsoleSample/Program.cs.
    - For LiveCameraSample, the keys should be entered into the Settings pane of the app. They will be persisted across sessions as user data.

I've got the API keys and inserted the Face API key to the Program.cs code and all of the API's into the settings.

It say's that it cannot find some namespaces as seen in the image:

[image]

Why does it say that the namespaces are not included in the Microsoft.ProjectOxford namespace ? Thanks

Edit: This was solved. After updating Nuget and all it still didn't work and the problem was that the pathname was too long.
What I did was downloading the project to desktop and than pressed extract files. 
It created a folder with a long name and inside was another folder with a long name so the path was big. 
Just put it in D or just extract here and not it will extract the folder inside the zip and not create another one with the folder inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing red squiggles because you're missing some dependent assemblies.  These are provided via NuGet, so you should download it by right-clicking on the project, and selecting `Manage NuGet packages...`.  The UI thereafter is hopefully self-explanatory.

Once the missing packages are pulled in from NuGet, you should be able to build+run the application.  Once you run it, there should be UI presented where you'd enter the requisite key.  The XAML for it is [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Samples-VideoFrameAnalysis/blob/779049ed3a6b17dabc79094bf3992733e1879bbf/Windows/LiveCameraSample/MainWindow.xaml#L46).

Comment: The Vision And Emotion dependent assemblies are installed but it can't fine them. When I've clicked Restore I got an error: "an error occured while trying to restore packeges.the path, file name or both are too long..."

Comment: It is a [known issue](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3324) that NuGet cannot support long path names, unfortunately. The only workaround I'm aware of is to shorten the root path of your project.

Comment: I find it wierd that Microsoft knows about this and are still naming the sample folder with such a long name. This helped, thanks